# How can I make Trello auto-login when Chrome starts?

Tags: trello, google-chrome, login

Does it make a difference if I use the same account I use for Chrome?

I really need it to be starting up when I ever I start Chrome, without having to sign in every time.

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy way to do this using Chrome's Basic Settings:

1. Open Chrome, log into Trello.
2. Go to Chrome options and choose "Re-open the pages that were open last".
3. Close Chrome without logging out of Trello and your Trello tab will be reopened automatically and log you in next time.